# About functions and little calculus

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Many a times I come upon an $x$ vs. $t$ graph in which the distance $x$ is given as a function of time like $x=f(t)=20+5t^2$.

Can its reverse be found? For example, given

```
at t=0 x=20
   t=1 x=25
   t=2 x=40
   t=3 x=65
   t=4 x=100
```

Also if acceleration is constant and given that the curve is a continuous, find the expression for $x=f(t)=?$

Please give a detailed proofs (I have just started calculus). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. This is my first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be addressed by the finite difference method, i.e. computing pairwise differences.

In the given case,

$$20, 25, 40, 65, 100\to5,15,25,35.$$

Repeating this process,

$$5,15,25,35\to10,10,10.$$

Having a constant second order difference confirms that the quadratic model is compatible.

Indeed, let $f(t)=\frac12at^2+bt+c$. The first order difference is

$$\Delta f(t)=f(t+1)-f(t)=(\frac12a(t+1)^2+b(t+1)+c)-(\frac12at^2+bt+c)=a(t+\frac12)+b.$$

And the second order one,

$$\Delta^2 f(t)=\Delta g(t)=g(t+1)-g(t)=(a(t+1+\frac12)+b)-(a(t+\frac12)+b)=a,$$

a constant.

Hence we have identified that the acceleration is $a=10$.

Comment: Having these five points through the same parabola does not guarantee that the motion has a constant acceleration (it could vary arbitrarily in between the data points), but that makes a reasonable hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

With the information given in the example you gave, you can't be sure you would find $f(t)$ as given in the exercise. You could plot the values in a graph, and using any plotting software, you can approximate the function, and you would obtain the same answer. However, you can have a very wiggly continuous function such that the values of $t=0,1,2,3,4..$ are those you gave. So to give you a picture of how could you solve it analitically, you would have to take very "little" intervals of $t$ so to be sure that your function (although continuous) doesn't do whatever she likes in the intervals of $t$ you took.